# Building Jenkins plugin tests with JenkinsRule class

Tags: java, junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to unit test Jenkins Plugins using JenkinsRule

All the tests suggest this kind of approach

```
package hudson.plugins.xxxx;
import hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild;
import hudson.model.FreeStyleProject;
import hudson.tasks.Shell;
import org.junit.*;
import org.jvnet.hudson.test.JenkinsRule;

public class Apptest{

  @Rule public JenkinsRule jenkinsRule = new JenkinsRule();

  @Test public void first() throws Exception {
    FreeStyleProject project = jenkinsRule.createFreeStyleProject();
    project.getBuildersList().add(new Shell("echo hello"));
    FreeStyleBuild build = project.scheduleBuild2(0).get();

  }
}
```

as per the example https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unit+Test

But jenkinsRule.createFreeStyleProject() is a protected method and wont let me call it. How Should I test the builder

Answer (score 2):

okay seems my pom.xml was out of date

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.499</version>
</parent>
```

This is one which works